# Is UNION ALL of two SELECTs over different tables executed in parallel?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If I have Spark SQL statement of the form `SELECT [...] UNION ALL SELECT [...]`, will the two `SELECT` statements be executed in parallel? In my specific use case the two `SELECT`s are querying two different database tables. In contrast to what I would have expected, the Spark UI seems to suggest that the two `SELECT` statements are performed sequentially.

== Update 1 ==

Below is the physical plan as displayed in the Spark UI:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Sort [avg_tip_pct#655 DESC NULLS LAST], true, 0
+- Exchange rangepartitioning(avg_tip_pct#655 DESC NULLS LAST, 4)
   +- *HashAggregate(keys=[neighborhood#163], functions=[avg(tip_pct#654)], output=[neighborhood#163, avg_tip_pct#655])
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(neighborhood#163, 4)
         +- *HashAggregate(keys=[neighborhood#163], functions=[partial_avg(tip_pct#654)], output=[neighborhood#163, sum#693, count#694L])
            +- *Project [neighborhood#163, (tip_amount#513 / total_amount#514) AS tip_pct#654]
               +- InMemoryTableScan [neighborhood#163, tip_amount#513, total_amount#514]
                     +- InMemoryRelation [pickup_latitude#511, pickup_longitude#512, tip_amount#513, total_amount#514, neighborhood#163, index#165], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
                           +- *Project [pickup_latitude#301, pickup_longitude#300, tip_amount#310, total_amount#313, neighborhood#163, index#165]
                              +- *Project [pickup_latitude#301, index#165, pickup_longitude#300, neighborhood#163, total_amount#313, point#524, polygon#164, tip_amount#310]
                                 +- *SortMergeJoin [curve#578], [curve#580], Inner, ((relation#581 = Within) || Within(point#524, polygon#164))
                                    :- *Sort [curve#578 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                                    :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(curve#578, 4)
                                    :     +- Generate inline(indexer(point#524, 30)), true, false, [curve#578, relation#579]
                                    :        +- Union
                                    :           :- *Project [pickup_latitude#301, pickup_longitude#300, tip_amount#310, total_amount#313, pointconverter(pickup_longitude#300, pickup_latitude#301) AS point#524]
                                    :           :  +- *Filter ((isnotnull(total_amount#313) && payment_type#306 IN (CREDIT,CRD,1)) && (total_amount#313 > 200.0))
                                    :           :     +- *Scan BigQueryTableRelation({datasetId=new_york, projectId=bigquery-public-data, tableId=tlc_yellow_trips_2014},org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@3bf2de09) [pickup_latitude#301,payment_type#306,pickup_longitude#300,total_amount#313,tip_amount#310] PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(total_amount), In(payment_type, [CREDIT,CRD,1]), GreaterThan(total_amount,200.0)], ReadSchema: struct<pickup_latitude:double,pickup_longitude:double,tip_amount:double,total_amount:double,point...
                                    :           +- *Project [pickup_latitude#436, pickup_longitude#435, tip_amount#445, total_amount#448, pointconverter(pickup_longitude#435, pickup_latitude#436) AS point#524]
                                    :              +- *Filter ((isnotnull(total_amount#448) && payment_type#441 IN (CREDIT,CRD,1)) && (total_amount#448 > 200.0))
                                    :                 +- *Scan BigQueryTableRelation({datasetId=new_york, projectId=bigquery-public-data, tableId=tlc_yellow_trips_2015},org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@3bf2de09) [payment_type#441,pickup_longitude#435,pickup_latitude#436,total_amount#448,tip_amount#445] PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(total_amount), In(payment_type, [CREDIT,CRD,1]), GreaterThan(total_amount,200.0)], ReadSchema: struct<pickup_latitude:double,pickup_longitude:double,tip_amount:double,total_amount:double,point...
                                    +- *Sort [curve#580 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                                       +- Exchange hashpartitioning(curve#580, 4)
                                          +- Generate inline(index#165), true, false, [curve#580, relation#581]
                                             +- InMemoryTableScan [neighborhood#163, polygon#164, index#165]
                                                   +- InMemoryRelation [neighborhood#163, polygon#164, index#165], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
                                                         +- *Project [UDF:metadata_string(metadata#13, neighborhood) AS neighborhood#163, polygon#12, index#15]
                                                            +- InMemoryTableScan [metadata#13, polygon#12, index#15]
                                                                  +- InMemoryRelation [point#10, polyline#11, polygon#12, metadata#13, valid#14, index#15], true, 10000, StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas), `neighborhoods`
                                                                        +- *Scan GeoJSONRelation(gs://miraisolutions/public/sparkgeo/nyc_neighborhoods.geojson,Map(type -> geojson, magellan.index -> true, magellan.index.precision -> 30, path -> gs://miraisolutions/public/sparkgeo/nyc_neighborhoods.geojson)) [point#10,polyline#11,polygon#12,metadata#13,valid#14,index#15] ReadSchema: struct<point:struct<type:int,xmin:double,ymin:double,xmax:double,ymax:double,x:double,y:double>,p...
```

Note the union of the two `SELECT`s present in the form of scans on `BigQueryTableRelation`. These seem to be executed sequentially.

Each of the BigQuery selects is being executed in a separate job (each with a single stage) - sequentially. I run a 5 node YARN cluster with 4 CPUs and 26GB of RAM each. I wonder whether the fact that I have a custom BigQuery data source matters here. I would expect it should not. In any case, for reference, the data source can be found here: github.com/miraisolutions/spark-bigquery

== Update 2 ==

In the Spark log I see the following log entry:

`` 17/12/19 14:36:24 INFO SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: SELECT `pickup_latitude` AS `pickup_latitude`, `pickup_longitude` AS `pickup_longitude`, `tip_amount` AS `tip_amount`, `total_amount` AS `total_amount`
FROM ((SELECT *
FROM `trips2014`)
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
FROM `trips2015`)) `ggcyamhubf`
WHERE (`payment_type` IN ("CREDIT", "CRD", "1")) ``

Spark optimizes this query and pushes the predicates down to the data source (BigQuery in this case). The corresponding BigQuery jobs, however, seem to execute fully sequentially, i.e. the second job is triggered only once the first one finishes.

Comment: Could that be that this is how BigQuery works where two parallel queries from the same client are executed one after another? Could you attach the query plan from web UI?

Comment: I don't have the query plan available right now but from the Spark logs it definitely looks like the `DataSource`'s `buildScan` (via `RelationProvider`) is called sequentially which would imply the sequential processing is a result of Spark's execution plan. I currently don't see anything that would imply it's a BigQuery limitation.

Comment: Too much guessing...too little data that would help us. The reason for possible sequential execution is just the number of CPUs available to process all the tasks that are part of the query. That's why we badly need the execution stats from web UI. Why don't you archive the logs --> https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#viewing-after-the-fact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** Yes (subject to CPU availability)

As a side note: If you're in doubt, you can also execute two SELECTs on their own threads followed by `union` (that again would also depend on the number of CPUs), but you would for sure have a truly parallel execution.

Let's use the (very basic) following query:

```
val q = spark.range(1).union(spark.range(2))
```

`explain` won't tell you about the final execution from CPU perspective, but at least gives you whether a whole-stage code generation is in use and how far up the query tree.

```
scala> q.explain
== Physical Plan ==
Union
:- *Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=8)
+- *Range (0, 2, step=1, splits=8)
```

In this example, the two `Range` physical operators (that are responsible for the two separate datasets) will get "codegend" and so their execution is pipelined. Their execution time is the time to finish processing all rows in partitions (as quick as it could ever be without dealing with the "mechanics" of the Java code itself which could use `System.sleep` or similar).

The RDD lineage of the query could give you more information on the query execution.

```
scala> q.rdd.toDebugString
res4: String =
(16) MapPartitionsRDD[17] at rdd at <console>:26 []
 |   MapPartitionsRDD[16] at rdd at <console>:26 []
 |   UnionRDD[15] at rdd at <console>:26 []
 |   MapPartitionsRDD[11] at rdd at <console>:26 []
 |   MapPartitionsRDD[10] at rdd at <console>:26 []
 |   ParallelCollectionRDD[9] at rdd at <console>:26 []
 |   MapPartitionsRDD[14] at rdd at <console>:26 []
 |   MapPartitionsRDD[13] at rdd at <console>:26 []
 |   ParallelCollectionRDD[12] at rdd at <console>:26 []
```

Unless I'm mistaken, since there are no stages in-between there's not much you can parallelize -- it's just a single stage with 16 partitions and it finishes as fast as the last task (from the 16 tasks to be scheduled).

That means that the order does matter in this case.

---

I also found [this JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22491) about `UNION ALL` that looks similar if not exactly like your case.

Comment: Yes, your first statement is correct. The DFs in the union are read in the same stage, so in your example where each DF has 8 partitions then you have a stage with 16 tasks to read the 2 DFs. There's no need to define the DF in a separate thread. You can verify this also in the Stage UI and looking at the Event Timeline. You should see the tasks across the DFs executing in parallel as expected.

Comment: I can see `InMemoryTableScan` which means you've cached some parts of the query, haven't you? (not that it matters, but worth asking). How do you know `UNION` executes `SELECT`s sequentially? I don't see the number of partitions per `BigQueryTableRelation`. 5 nodes x 4 CPUs = 20 CPUs <-- that's not very impressive, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you are right: some parts of the query are cached. As you mentioned, the cluster is not very big but should be fit for purpose in this case. Please see my second update in the question to hopefully provide you more relevant details ...

Comment: The BigQuery data source implements `PrunedFilteredScan` and the `buildScan` method triggers a BigQuery job (see https://github.com/miraisolutions/spark-bigquery/blob/develop/src/main/scala/com/miraisolutions/spark/bigquery/BigQueryTableRelation.scala#L56). The execution of the BigQuery job is blocking. Would that be a problem here?