# Pyspark with Joblib giving me ambiguous result

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, teradata, joblib

I am trying to fetch data from teradata--

```
select ... from table1_1
union all
select .. from table_2
union all
select ... from table_3
```

**NOTE: One or more `select ..` may fail which should not cause whole union to fail.**

```py
from .base import Base
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import re
import pandas as pd

class TeradataWithSpark(Base):
    def __init__(self, spark, host=None, port=None, database=None, username=None, password=None):
        super().__init__(spark, host, port, database, username, password)
        self._reader = self._spark.read.format("jdbc") \
                .option("url", f'jdbc:teradata://{self._host}/Database={self._database},LOGMECH=LDAP') \
                .option("user", self._username) \
                .option("password", self._password) \
                .option("driver", "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver")

    def run_query(self, query, return_pandasDF=True):
        spark_df = self._reader.option('dbtable', f"({query}) as tbl").load()
        if return_pandasDF:
            return spark_df.toPandas()
        else:
            return spark_df

    def run_queries_and_union_all(self, queries, return_pandasDF=True):
        def run(query):
            try:
                return self._reader.option('dbtable', f"({query}) as tbl").load().toPandas()
            except Exception as e:
                return None
        
        dfs = Parallel(n_jobs=10, prefer='threads')(delayed(run)(q) for q in queries)
        concat_df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True)
        if return_pandasDF:
            return concat_df
        else:
            return self._spark.createDataFrame(concat_df)

    def split_query_and_run_individually(self, query, separator='union all', return_pandasDF=True):
        queries = re.split(separator, query, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        return self.run_queries_and_union_all(queries, return_pandasDF)
```

As you can see `split_query_and_run_individually` method splits the query based on `union all` then runs all of the sub queries in parallel threads `n_jobs=10`.

But the problem I am facing is that the data is corrupted like this

```
n_jobs = 1
                               src_tbl  total_count   data_date
0     dsl_dim_mdm_....................           61  2022-03-17
1     dsl_agg_call....................      3992202  2022-03-27
2      dsl_call_ac....................       924719  2022-03-27
3      dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
4                 ....................         6821  2022-03-31
5     dsl_dim_geo_....................      8610038  2022-04-05
6              dsl....................        67116  2022-03-31
7           dsl_rl....................      2087669  2022-04-06
8             dsl_....................          154  2022-04-01
9             dsl_....................        85630  2022-03-27
10  dsl_selling_da....................           53  2021-03-03
11  dsl_speaker_ev....................        17765  2022-03-31
12       dsl_speak....................        26269  2022-08-24
13   dsl_speaker_e....................         4202  2022-04-05
14              ds....................          268  2022-03-31
15      dsl_rltn_r....................       255794  2022-03-18
16     dsl_rltn_nr....................        12088  2022-03-18
17        dsl_rapp....................        81182  2022-01-01
18   dsl_dim_physi....................       109299  2022-03-31
19             dsl....................         4265  2022-02-01
20         dsl_fac....................       117978  2022-04-03
21      dsl_coachi....................          242  2022-03-31
22   dsl_speaker_e....................        16653  2022-03-31
23     dsl_dim_cal....................        17817  2099-12-31
24    dsl_rltn_nrt....................         3304  2022-02-01
Time took: 3.4742537260055544 minutes
-----------
n_jobs=10
                              src_tbl  total_count   data_date
0             dsl_sel................        85630  2022-03-27
1             dsl_sel................        85630  2022-03-27
2             dsl_sel................        85630  2022-03-27
3             dsl_sel................        85630  2022-03-27
4             dsl_sel................        85630  2022-03-27
5             dsl_sel................        85630  2022-03-27
6             dsl_sel................        85630  2022-03-27
7             dsl_sel................        85630  2022-03-27
8             dsl_sel................        85630  2022-03-27
9             dsl_sel................        85630  2022-03-27
10  dsl_speaker_event................        17765  2022-03-31
11   dsl_speaker_even................         4202  2022-04-05
12   dsl_speaker_even................         4202  2022-04-05
13              dsl_s................          268  2022-03-31
14        dsl_rapper_................        81182  2022-01-01
15        dsl_rapper_................        81182  2022-01-01
16     dsl_rltn_nrtl_................        12088  2022-03-18
17        dsl_rapper_................        81182  2022-01-01
18   dsl_dim_physicia................       109299  2022-03-31
19             dsl_cu................         4265  2022-02-01
20         dsl_fact_f................       117978  2022-04-03
21      dsl_coaching_................          242  2022-03-31
22   dsl_speaker_even................        16653  2022-03-31
23     dsl_dim_call_c................        17817  2099-12-31
24    dsl_rltn_nrtl_r................         3304  2022-02-01
Time took: 1.8048373858133953 minutes
-----------
n_jobs=-1
                            src_tbl  total_count   data_date
0   dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
1   dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
2   dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
3   dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
4   dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
5   dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
6   dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
7   dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
8   dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
9   dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
10  dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
11  dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
12  dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
13  dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
14  dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
15  dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
16  dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
17  dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
18  dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
19  dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
20  dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
21  dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
22  dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
23  dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
24  dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
25  dsl_dim_acc....................         4762  2022-03-31
-----------
```

As you can see as I increase the number of threads the result becomes ambiguous. What is happening is that the results from each query are overlapping with each other.

I have also implemented the same class with [`teradatasql`](https://pypi.org/project/teradatasql/) library which works just fine with n_jobs=-1. I think `self._reader.option('dbtable', f"({query}) as tbl").load()` is getting messed up in threads. I tried with `ThreadpoolExecutor` but similar result. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
Versions

```
Python 3.6.8
Spark 2.4.0-cdh6.3.4
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you doing distribution and implementing parallelism here, while Spark supposes to be the one doing that?

Comment: I don't think for SQL union all spark runs the queries separately, as you can see with increased n_jobs the time to process also reduces.

Comment: All I'm saying is, why don't you read and union by Spark? Just don't use joblib at all.

Comment: How can I read multiple tables in parallel? I don't have much experience in pyspark, but I can see the `.load()` is synchronous..can you let me know any resource to parallelize jdbc reads in spark?

Comment: I have found this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192893/how-to-read-and-write-multiple-tables-in-parallel-in-spark but does not have valid answer

Comment: It seems the `union all`, altought the speed is very less are run in parallel from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837955/is-union-all-of-two-selects-over-different-tables-executed-in-parallel And one thing also to mention is that some of the `select ...`  statements may fail, so we have to ensure that if anyone fails the whole `union all` should not fail.

Comment: `load()` doesn't actually load all of your data into memory, just metadata like schemas, so you can do that for all tables then union them all together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @pltc, here is one solution. Although it is very slow compared to `teradatasql` library with multithreading although FAIR schedulers on

```py
from .base import Base
import re
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from functools import reduce

class TeradataWithSpark(Base):
    def __init__(self, spark, host=None, port=None, database=None, username=None, password=None):
        super().__init__(spark, host, port, database, username, password)
        self._reader = self._spark.read.format("jdbc") \
                .option("url", f'jdbc:teradata://{self._host}/Database={self._database},LOGMECH=LDAP') \
                .option("user", self._username) \
                .option("password", self._password) \
                .option("driver", "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver")

    def run_query(self, query, return_pandasDF=True):
        # spark_df = self._reader.option('dbtable', f"({query}) as tbl").load()
        # if return_pandasDF:
        #     return spark_df.toPandas()
        # else:
        #     return spark_df
        return self.split_query_and_run_individually(query, r'union all', return_pandasDF)

    def run_queries_and_union_all(self, queries, return_pandasDF=True):     
        dataframes = []
        for each_query in queries:
            try:
                spark_df = self._reader.option('dbtable', f"({each_query}) as tbl").load()
                dataframes.append(spark_df)
            except Exception as e:
                # simply ignoring the query
                print(f'Error while reading the query {each_query}')
            
        concat_sparkDf = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dataframes)
        if return_pandasDF:
            return concat_sparkDf.toPandas()
        else:
            return concat_sparkDf

    def split_query_and_run_individually(self, query, separator=r'union all', return_pandasDF=True):
        queries = re.split(separator, query, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        return self.run_queries_and_union_all(queries, return_pandasDF)
```